# Average memory access time

Tags: cpu-architecture

I would like to know did I solve the equation correctly below

find the average memory access time for process with a process with a 3ns clock cycle time, a miss penalty of 40 clock cycle, a miss rate of .08 misses per instruction, and a cache access time of 1 clock cycle

AMAT = Hit Time + Miss Rate * Miss Penalty

Hit Time = 3ns, Miss Penalty = 40ns, Miss Rate = 0.08
AMAT = 3 + 0.08 * 40 = 6.2ns

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Miss Penalty". Be more careful to avoid trivial mistakes.

The question that you tried to answer cannot actually be answered, since you are given 0.08 misses *per instruction* but you don't know the average number of memory accesses per instruction. In an extreme case, if only 8 percent of instructions accessed memory, then every memory access would be a miss.

Comment: what do you mean check the miss penalty. So the 40 is wrong, why?